# Is there any 'switching IC' to replace 'transistor switch' for switching the 12 volts LED array?

Tags: transistors, switches, switching, led-driver

I have created a 12 volts LED array, and used a MOSFET to switch this panel. Do we have any switching IC which can switch it instead? 
I will have five LED panels similar like this to switch at the end. I thought an  IC may reduce overall circuit complexity.

LED Panel voltage: 12 volts
LED Panel current: 250 mA
Switching MCU: 5 V AVR

Comment: What advantage do you imagine in replacing a FET with a IC?

Comment: I will have five LED panels similar like this to switch at the end. I thought IC may reduce overall circuit complexity.

Comment: Yes and no, depending the led array you want to switch and how you wish to switch it.

Comment: @dannyf I want to switch 12 volts and 250mA LED array. I have Arduino controller as a control input.

Comment: You are looking for a transistor or mosfet array. Or a dual or quad mosfet ic. These are simply multiple mosfet in a single package. Sometimes with a common pin. It may make your board slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for makes no sense.  To switch 12 V at 250 mA from a 5 V digital signal, all you need is a FET.  The IRLML2502 would do nicely, for example.  No other parts are needed.  The FET has three terminals.  One goes to the control signal, one is the output, and the third goes to ground.

Any IC is going to require at least a power and ground connection in addition to the input and output signals.  Clearly that's not simpler.  The IRLML2502 is pretty much a ideal switch in this application, so it's hard to imagine what exactly the advantage is of some unspecified integrated circuit.  This FET comes in a SOT-23 package, so you're not going to find a IC that is smaller.  What would this IC do for you that the single FET doesn't?

Again, your request makes no sense.

Comment: Okay. IRLML2502 looks great. I shall try that. Thank you

Comment: I had similar problem some times ago - need to switch more power with AVR pins. I used transistors for that, but the PCB was complicated, as I had hard time to organise the array of all those transistors, each with 3 pins to mach the lines from TQFP with this. An IC with (eventual power,) GND and one row of inputs on one side and second row of outputs on other side would help me a lot. Even if it would just consist of a row of IRLML250's with common ground and maybe some resistors. Same reason, why many resistor arrays are made, even if resistor have just 2 pins. (for 8R array you save 7 pins)

Comment: @gilhad transistor arrays exist. The ULN is a common one. And there are resistor arrays that don't have a common pin, so they would still be 16 pins for a 8 resistor array.

Comment: There was not avaiable at that time in my town and I was not used to buy online - and the post would cost more than the transistors anyway. But times changes and the ULN is good tip, I will buy some just "for the case". Anyway the more arguments, why the Olins answer is invalid - the original request make perfect sence in many scenarios